# How to create language object from language string (e.g. 'en')?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

As in question, ofcourse I am asking about Drupal function for this job.

So I need function that get language string as param (e.g 'en','pl' etc) and returns me standard Drupal language object. Similar to global $language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would use the following code; with `mymodule_get_language_obj($name, FALSE)` you get a language object only if it has been enabled.

```
function mymodule_get_language_obj($name, $all = TRUE) {
  if ($all) {
    $languages = language_list();
  }
  else {
    $languages = language_list('enabled');
    $languages = $languages[1];
  }

  return isset($languages[$name]) ? $languages[$name] : NULL;
}
```

Notice that on Drupal 7.43 (and possibly, on previous Drupal 7 versions), `language_list()` returns an array of objects, contrary to what reported in [a comment posted in the documentation page](https://api.drupal.org/comment/27124#comment-27124).

> When calling:
>
> ```
> <?php
>   $languages = language_list('enabled');
> ?>
> ```
>
> You can expect the return value to be:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $languages = array(
>     '1' => 
>         array( 
>             'en' => array('language'=>'en', 'name'=>'English', ... ), 
>             'fr' => array('language'=> 'fr', 'name' => 'Francais', ... ),
>         )
>     );
> ?>
> ```
>
> The index being 1 because it's the value of the 'enabled' column.

With Drupal 7.43, I obtained the following:

#### *Locale* module not installed

- Output of `print_r(language_list('enabled'));`

```
    Array(
      [1] => Array(
        [en] => stdClass Object(
          [language] => en
          [name] => English
          [native] => English
          [direction] => 0
          [enabled] => 1
          [plurals] => 0
          [formula] =>
          [domain] =>
          [prefix] =>
          [weight] => 0
          [javascript] =>
        )
      )
    )
```

- Output of `print_r(language_list());`

```
    Array(
      [en] => stdClass Object(
        [language] => en
        [name] => English
        [native] => English
        [direction] => 0
        [enabled] => 1
        [plurals] => 0
        [formula] =>
        [domain] =>
        [prefix] =>
        [weight] => 0
        [javascript] =>
      )
    )
```

#### *Locale* module installed, and *Esperanto* enabled as additional language

- Output of `print_r(language_list('enabled'));`

```
    Array(
      [1] => Array(
        [en] => stdClass Object(
          [language] => en
          [name] => English
          [native] => English
          [direction] => 0
          [enabled] => 1
          [plurals] => 0
          [formula] =>
          [domain] =>
          [prefix] =>
          [weight] => 0
          [javascript] =>
        )
        [eo] => stdClass Object(
          [language] => eo
          [name] => Esperanto
          [native] => Esperanto
          [direction] => 0
          [enabled] => 1
          [plurals] => 0
          [formula] =>
          [domain] =>
          [prefix] => eo
          [weight] => 0
          [javascript] =>
        )
      )
    )
```

- Output of `print_r(language_list());`

```
    Array(
      [en] => stdClass Object(
        [language] => en
        [name] => English
        [native] => English
        [direction] => 0
        [enabled] => 1
        [plurals] => 0
        [formula] =>
        [domain] =>
        [prefix] =>
        [weight] => 0
        [javascript] =>
      )
      [eo] => stdClass Object(
        [language] => eo
        [name] => Esperanto
        [native] => Esperanto
        [direction] => 0
        [enabled] => 1
        [plurals] => 0
        [formula] =>
        [domain] =>
        [prefix] => eo
        [weight] => 0
        [javascript] =>
      )
    )
```

The equivalent code for Drupal 8 would be the following one.

```
function mymodule_get_language_obj($name) {
  $languages = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguages();

  return isset($languages[$name]) ? $languages[$name] : NULL;
}
```

Note that Drupal 8 version of the code returns instances of the [`Locale`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Language!Language.php/class/Language/8) class, not the `stdClass` class.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`language_list()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/language_list/7) function:

```
<?php

function get_langugage_object($language) {
  $installed_languages = language_list();
  return $installed_languages[$language];
}

?>
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer because it actually gives you an object, the accepted answer however returns a string of the language....